# Apache Spark shortest job scala

Tags: scala, csv, apache-spark

I am new to Apache Spark and scala programming. I am writing a code in scala using apache spark api docs. My goal is to create a graph and deploy objects and compute shortest path.I have written a program to generate a csv file of object which I want to use. It consists of vehicleID,source,Destination.
It is as follows:

```
[My sample csv file][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtSVz.png
```

My code to generate CSV file

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter
import java.io.FileWriter

import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import scala.util.Random
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter

import scala.collection.mutable

class MakeCSV() {
  def csvBuilder(dx:Int){
    val outputfile= new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("vehicles.csv"))
    val csvWriter= new CSVWriter(outputfile)
    val csvFields= Array("Vehicle-id","Source","Destination")
    val vehicleID=(0 to dx).toList
    val sourceList=mutable.MutableList[String]()
    val destinationList=mutable.MutableList[String]()
    var i,sx,sy,dsx,dsy=0
    for(i<-0 to dx){
      sx=Random.nextInt(dx)
      sy=Random.nextInt(dx)
      dsx=Random.nextInt(dx)
      dsy=Random.nextInt(dx)
      sourceList.+=((sx,sy).toString())
      destinationList.+=((dsx,dsy).toString())
    }
    var listOfRecords = new ListBuffer[Array[String]]()
    listOfRecords += csvFields
    for (i<- 0 to dx){
      listOfRecords+=Array(i.toString,sourceList(Random.nextInt(sourceList.length)),destinationList(Random.nextInt(destinationList.length)))
    }
    csvWriter.writeAll(listOfRecords.asJava)
    csvWriter.close()
  }
}
```

My main file:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter

import scala.io.StdIn
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.graphx.Graph
import org.apache.spark.graphx.util.GraphGenerators
object MainFile {
  def main(args:Array[String]):Unit={

//    Vehicle CSV file Generation
    println("Enter the number of cars")
    val input=StdIn.readInt()
    val makecsv= new MakeCSV()
    makecsv.csvBuilder(input)

//   Spark Job Configuration
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("DjikstraShortestPath")
    val sc= new SparkContext(conf)

//    Graph Generation
    println("Enter the number of rows for grid")
    val row= StdIn.readInt()
    println("Enter the number of columns for grid")
    val column = StdIn.readInt()
    val graph:Graph[(Int, Int), Double]=GraphGenerators.gridGraph(sc,row,column)

//    Vehicle File opening
//    For each Vehicle compute shortest path using source destination in csv file

  }
}
```

Now I want to open that csv file and using its source and destination I want to compute shortest path for each vehicle using the graph generated above. Can anyone help me? How to open the csv file read it and find shortest path